# Why do these divs overlap each other?

Tags: html, css

I have a little bit of code in which the DIVs are overlapping each other. I've removed code that doesn't affect the problem.

The idea is, that if you scroll, you scroll to the right thru some cards, and if you're through, you scroll down to the next set of cards.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.horizontal {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.title {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}

.scroll-view {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 90vh;
    width: 90vh;
    height: 100vw;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-90vh);
    transform-origin: right top;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.container {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: right top;
    max-height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "vertical">
            <div class = "horizontal">
                <div class = "title">
                    <h1>horizontal-title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class = "scroll-view">
                    <div class = "container">
                        container
                    </div>
                    <div class = "container">
                        container
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why so much `transform`s? that is what make it overlap

Comment: The transforms are there to make you scroll left to right, but I think if catches the problem.

Comment: As I understand, you need a horizontal scroll, if it is, you do not need rotation to make a horizontal scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they overlap because you `rotate` them on the side. If you want to separate them, just add a margin between them - so when they rotate they won't be rotate on top of each other.

In this case I added margin to the second container.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.horizontal {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.scroll-view {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 90vh;
  width: 90vh;
  height: 100vw;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-90vh);
  transform-origin: right top;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.container {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
  max-height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vertical">
    <div class="horizontal">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>horizontal-title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-view">
        <div class="container">
          container
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px">
          container
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```